# Is it possible to divide a Gradle build script into separate source files?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, modularity

Consider this toy `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
  id "java"
}

import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem;

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

def pathExists(pathname) {
  // Returns true iff pathame is an existing file or directory
  try {
    // This may throw an error for a Windows pathname, c:/path/to/thing
    if (file(pathname).exists()) {
      return true;
    }
  } catch (GradleException e) {
    // I don't care
  }

  if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
    try {
      // If we're on Windows, try to make c:/path/to/thing work
      if (file("file:///${pathname}").exists()) {
        return true;
      }
    } catch (GradleException e) {
      // I don't care
    }
  }

  return false
}

def someVariable = "absent"
if (pathExists("/tmp")) {
  someVariable = "present"
}

task someCommonTask() {
  doLast {
    println("Did some setup stuff: ${someVariable}")
  }
}

task someATask(dependsOn: ["someCommonTask"]) {
  doLast {
    println("A: ${someVariable}")
  }
}

task someBTask(dependsOn: ["someCommonTask"]) {
  def otherVariable = someVariable == "absent" || pathExists("/etc")
  doLast {
    println("B: ${otherVariable}")
  }
}
```

Is it possible to reorganize this build file so that `someATask` is in `a.gradle` and `someBTask` is in `b.gradle`? I've made some attempts to use `apply from:` without success and, if the answer is on this page: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html it eludes me.

In the real project, there would be a couple of dozen tasks in each of those subordinate files and the goal of dividing up the `build.gradle` file isn't to have them be subprojcts, per se, they're just logical groupings of tasks.

Comment: Please add the failed attempt with `apply from: ...`

Comment: Move `someTaskA` into `a.gradle`, add `apply from: "a.gradle"` before `someCommonTask`. Then `gradle someATask` fails because `someVariable` is not known to `someATask`.

Answer (score 4):

This split can be done using `apply from: ...` to separate the files.
E.g.

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id "java"
}

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

ext {
  someVariable = "absent" // XXX
}

apply from: "setup.gradle" // XXX
apply from: "common.gradle" // XXX

task someATask(dependsOn: ["someCommonTask"]) {
  doLast {
    println("A: ${someVariable}")
  }
}
```

`setup.gradle`:

```
task setup() {
  someVariable = "present"
}
```

`common.gradle`:

```
task someCommonTask(dependsOn: ["setup"]) {
  doLast {
    println("Did some setup stuff: ${someVariable}")
  }
}
```

```
# gradle someATask

> Task :someCommonTask
Did some setup stuff: present

> Task :someATask
A: present

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 403ms
```

My guess, the problems you are facing are with toplevel code and not
using properties.

Comment: Thank you, that's certainly a better starting point. Not quite sure how my `pathExists` funtion will work into it but I'll give it a try!